# Setting current category to active

Tags: timber

When on a category page I'm hoping to add an "active" class the current pages relevant link to show which category is selected in the menu.

Currently I'm listing all post categories and linking to their relevant pages via

```
{% for cat in categories %}

    <li><a style="margin: 0;" href="{{ cat.link }}" class="">{{cat.name}}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```

I have tried using if statements but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by setting the current category to active like this:

```
{% for cat in categories %}

     <li><a style="margin: 0;" href="{{ cat.link }}" class="menu-item {% if category|capitalize == cat.name %}active{% endif %}">{{cat.name}}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```